# Can Kryptonite affect Superman's mind?

Tags: dc, superman, batman

I was watching Superman/Batman: Public Enemies, and Lex Luthor framed Superman for killing Metallo by stating that the gigantic asteroid made of kryptonite that was approaching Earth, was affecting his mind. It seemed like a part of his big speech to frame him, so I didn't pay attention. Later on, Batman asks him "*Can* it affect your mind?", to which Superman replies "No. I mean... It never has" which lead me to believe that he wasn't exactly sure about it. Does anyone know?

Comment: In Smallville, red kryptonite removes Clark's inhibitions. I'm not sure if this was a deviation from the comics, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a list from the wikipedia page on kryptonite.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite) The references check out.

Regarding effects to Superman's mind:

1. Red Debuted in Adventure Comics #252 (Sept. 1958). Originally just weakened Superman, but to a greater degree. Later caused bizarre behaviour and transformations.
2. Silver  Debuted in Superman's Pal, Jimmy Olsen #70 (July 1963). Revealed by Jimmy Olsen to be a hoax. In Superman/ Batman #49 (Aug. 2008), silver kryptonite was re-introduced, on this occasion shown to be authentic as it causes Kryptonians to suffer from delusions.
3. Red-Gold    Debuted in Superman #178 (July 1965). Temporarily deprives Kryptonians of their memories.
4. Red-Green-Gold  Debuted in Superman #192 (Jan. 1967). An imaginary story in which the alloy permanently removes the character's abilities and memories of ever having been Superman.
5. Black   Debuted in Supergirl #2 (vol. 5, Oct. 2005). Can split a Kryptonian into two separate entities: one good and the other evil. (this one may or may not count, being that it creates a separate superman... but I threw it in anyway)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it affects him the way it does is IMO similar to how they draw power from the sun, due to the Kryptonian ability to absorb radiation causes them to absorb the harmful kryptonite radiation much more quickly than humans(who it gives cancer to after prolonged exposure) basically making the root of Kryptonian power is also the root of their ultimate weakness. I could be completely wrong though

Comment: We need a supported answer here, not just an opinion.